# Return characters

Tags: c, getchar

This is some sample code from *The C Programming Language by Ritchie & Kernighan*.

```
int c;
        while((c=getchar())!=EOF) {
            putchar(c);
        }
```

Notice that putchar referes to a variable of type *int*. Why is it possible to return and display both characters and integers with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int` is usually represented by 4 bytes while a `char` is actually just 1 byte of data. You can easily store a full character and more in the single `int` that `getchar()` returns. When an int is passed to `putchar(int)` it just lops off the extra space before displaying it. This technique is useful for passing `EOF` which is actually not a `char` at all, but an `int` that signals the end of the file.

Comment: note that the reason int is used instead of char is because the system needs to be able to signal EOF - and it uses a special return value, -1 (which is equivalent to the EOF constant) to do so. Since this -1 doesn't fit into the char, the result of getchar() is instead stored as an int.

Comment: The wording makes this sound like an int is usually 4 bytes (true) and a char is usually 1 byte (not exactly, because a char is *always* 1 byte).  Still, +1 for a good answer.

Comment: @mfrankli: You *can* put -1 into a `char` if the implementation's `char` type is signed, which many are, and the conversion rules allow `-1` to be converted to `char` type if it is signed. The reason `getchar` returns `int` is because it is *always* signed, and `EOF` is defined to be any negative number (not necessarily -1, but it usually is).

Comment: @dreamlax true - my comment was a major simplification

Answer (score 1):

The type char is nothing but an integer which is in most cases just a 8-bit byte. The type int is an integer, which is usually wider and so can keep all the possible values a char can keep. In order to make the check work, it must hold that `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)`. Almost always it is so. But if I remember well, it is said that the standard does not mandate this; it means that the only portable and safe way to check if the already read EOF is a real end of file or not, it's to check with `feof(FILE *)`. (E.g. if on your system CHAR_BIT is 16, sizeof(char) == 1 by definition, but sizeof(int) could be 1 too).

Comment: The standard guarantees only `sizeof(long) >= sizeof(int) >= sizeof(short) >= sizeof(char)` and I know some DSP (from TI) that have `CHAR_BIT == 32` and `sizeof (long)=1`

Comment: though, I daresay, on those machines what you do most of the time is not file I/O picking a char per time; so on common machines we work every day on, it's a non-issue; but it's worth mentioning it, of course.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` returns `int` so that it can *reliably* hold the `EOF` value (which is defined to be any negative integer, and in most implementations it is -1). The `char` type may be signed or unsigned depending on the implementation. If it is signed, then it *may* be able to hold the `EOF` value provided that `EOF` is within the range of a `signed char` type, and if it is unsigned then it may become indistinguishable from an actual character value when `EOF` is converted to the `unsigned char` type.

Comment: I believe `getchar` returns an int because that function existed before K&R added function prototypes to the language. At that time *all* functions returned an int. They then used this fact to squeeze the EOF value in.